# Create success message on php form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm trying to make a php mail form display a success message upon a successful submit.
I'm new to php and I'm not sure how to make this work.
As it sits now, after submit, the site just reloads at the top of the page. I'd like it to refresh at the contact div and display a success message.

Contact div html:

```
<div class="contact-wrapper" >
  <div class="contact">
    <div class="contact-left" id="contact">
        <?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
            echo "Thank you for your message.";
        }
        $mail_form = include('php/mail_form.php'); ?>
    </div> <!-- end div contact -->
```

Contact from PHP:

```
<?php
function spamcheck($field)
  {
  //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //filter_var() validates the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
  {//if "email" is filled out, proceed

  //check if the email address is invalid
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    echo "Invalid input";
    }
  else
    {//send email
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    mail("idc615@gmail.com", "Subject: $subject",
    $message, "From: $email" );
    header("location: index.php");
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you want to refresh without reloading entire page you should use AJAX

Comment: If the div is in an html (static) file you can't do it (without AJAX). If it's a php file - you can pass an argument to the page that will be used in order to display the message.

Comment: Please include your HTML markup, too.

Comment: How can I wrap this in a php file?

Comment: `I'd like it to refresh at the contact div` -- I don't understand why everyone's suggesting AJAX here.

Comment: after `header(location)` you don't have `Request[email]` anymore. Try `header("location: index.php?success=1");` and use `if (isset($_GET['success'])) {
            echo "Thank you for your message.";
        }`

Comment: @AlexandrPerfilov this is one step closer. The success message now shows, however the page still reloads at the top of the page, and not at the contact area. How can I make the page reload at the contact area?

Comment: @eloist, ajax only. it's not hard, just google a bit

Answer (score 4):

Try this code... You need to halt your script for some time so that user can see success or failure message. Without sleep user will not be able to see message as header will execute immediately.

```
if(mail("idc615@gmail.com", "Subject: $subject",$message, "From: $email" )){
   echo "Thank you for your message";
   sleep(2); // sleep for 2 seconds. Enough to display success message
   //header will execute after 2000ms(2s)
   header("location: index.php");
}else{
   echo "Unable to send message";
   sleep(2); // sleep for 2 seconds 
   header("location: index.php");
}
```

or try code given below:

in Contact from PHP

```
if(mail("idc615@gmail.com", "Subject: $subject",$message, "From: $email" )){
   header("location: index.php?status=1");
}else{ 
   header("location: index.php?status=0");
}
```

in index.php

```
 if(isset($_GET['status'])){
     $status = $_GET['status'];
     if($status == 1){
        echo "Thank you for your message";
     }else if($status == 0){
        echo "Unable to send message";
     }
 }
```

Comment: really sleep its first time I heard this would you mind explain?

Comment: sleep halts execution of php scripts for some time(time passed as arguments)... http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php. Above script will halt for 2seconds & then execution starts from header()..

Comment: ok but. I thought we can't change header when the output is sent.

Comment: btw if you check the manual you will get that the input is in second so I think you meant 2 not 2000

Comment: The page never loads with this code. I even changed 2000 to 2 and still wont load.

Comment: better way is to send success or failure as GET variables in header as  header("location: index.php?status =1") for success &  header("location: index.php?status =0") for failure

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

if(isset($_POST['contactrgtr']))
{
$query = "insert into contact_us(name,email,message)values('$name','$email','$message')";
$res = mysql_query($query);
if($res){
     $message = 'Your Message Successfully Sent';
     include_once('contact.php'); } `
```

Then in `contact.php` page you have to define `<?php $message ?>`.